# Progress bar + Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, qprogressbar

1. Как сделать так, чтобы когда нажимаешь на кнопку, 
   прогресс бар заполнялся на `1%`
2. Как сделать так, чтобы когда заполнится прогресс бар на 100%, 
   он обновлялся до `0`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from GuI import Ui_Dialog

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()  
ui.setupUi(dialog)
dialog.show()

def progress_bar():
    progress_bar = (start(100,))

ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(progress_bar)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(429, 300)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 230, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Dialog)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 61, 19))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Dialog)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 421, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Майнить"))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "..."))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Привет,это моя игра \"Мамкин майнер\" одним словом,это кликер."))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Что-бы начать \"Майнить\" нажмите кнопку \" Майнить\" да это звучит глупо."))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Версия игры-V.1"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Возле кнопки \"Майнить\" есть кнопка \"Настройка\"Там можно изменить сложно-"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "сть.Игра была напис
```

Comment: Приведите минимально-воспроизводимый пример, в котором вы хотите это сделать.

Comment: Сделал код кодом, не добавляйте больше скринами.

Comment: Смотрите,пользователь нажимает кнопку,и на прогресс баре,появляется 1%.И так до 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from GuI import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(429, 300)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 230, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Dialog)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 61, 19))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Dialog)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 421, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 411, 20))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Майнить"))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "..."))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Привет,это моя игра \"Мамкин майнер\" одним словом,это кликер."))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Что-бы начать \"Майнить\" нажмите кнопку \" Майнить\" да это звучит глупо."))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Версия игры-V.1"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Возле кнопки \"Майнить\" есть кнопка \"Настройка\"Там можно изменить сложно-"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "сть.Игра была напис..."))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):     
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)     
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.progress_bar)
        self.step = 0
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.step)
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)        
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_func)
        
        
    def progress_bar(self):
        self.timer.start(300)        

    def update_func(self):
        self.step += 1
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.step)        
        if self.step == 100:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.step = 0
            self.progressBar.setValue(self.step)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dialog()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]